# Given an array, how does the count in Numpy add up?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given this array:

```
[[5 0 3 3]
 [7 9 3 5]
 [2 4 7 6]]
```

How does `np.count_nonzero(x < 6)` result in 8?

`{5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 4}` - These are the non-zero values that are less than 6 and the count of them is 7.

`np.count_nonzero(x > 6)` returns 3.  I find 3 values greater than 6 below:
`{7,9,7}`

There are only 10 values in the array that are not 6 or 0, so the individual counts don't add up to 10.
8 + 3 = 11.

Comment: Look at `x<6` itself.  How many True?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `x < 6` is not equal to `x`, but instead it is comparing each element with `6`.

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[5,0,3,3], [7,9,3,5],[2,4,7,6]])
print(x < 6)
```

Output:

```
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False]])
```

And `np.count_nonzero()` is equivalent of counting non `False` (or `True`) elements in the output which is:

```
np.count_nonzero(x < 6)
# 8
np.sum(x < 6)
#8
```

And for the last part, why they don't add up to `11` is because the last element is `6`. So:

```py
np.count_nonzero(x < 6) + np.count_nonzero(x > 6) + np.count_nonzero(x == 6) 
# 12
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly along the lines of what I was thinking.